# TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() > int() retrieving from postgres database

Tags: python, flask, psycopg2

```
cur = conn.cursor()

result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s", [username])
if result > 0:
    data = cur.fetchone()
    password = data['password']

if sha256_crypt.verify(password_given, password):
    app.logger.info('PASSWORD MATCHED')
else:
    app.logger.info('PASSWORD Not MATCHED')
```

this is the actual code am using. i think the error is coming from variable 'result', i want it to get the stored password as dictionary.

Comment: cur.execute() returns `None` http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute under normal circumstances (or throws an exception if there is a problem). You are assigning the value `None` to the variable `result` and then when you run the line `if result > 0` you are trying to check if `None` is less than 0. The `NoneType() > int()` error message is telling you that `None` is unorderable. It can't order `None` as less ( or equal or greater) than 0. @piro has the answer below for you, mark that correct.

Answer (score 1):

`cur.execute()` doesn't return the result: you have to get the result using `cur.fetchone()`. If no result is found it will return `None`, otherwise it will return the tuple, or the dict, according to the cursor class used:

```
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s", [username])
data = cur.fetchone()
if data:
    password = data['password']
```

Answer (score 0):

Put single quote around `%s` Because `username` is a String

```
result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '%s'"%str(username))

if result.rowcount >0
```

Corretion

```
cur = conn.cursor()

result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s", [username])
data = cur.fetchone()
if result.rowcount > 0:
    password = data['password']


    if sha256_crypt.verify(password_given, password):
        app.logger.info('PASSWORD MATCHED')
    else:
        app.logger.info('PASSWORD Not MATCHED')
```

Comment: Thanks. but when i put single quote, the error changed to "syntax error near the user name.

Comment: Edited the answer Can you check now ??@nova

Comment: i tried this too, the error now goes back to unorderable types: NoneType() > int()

Comment: use `result.rowcount`

Comment: still the 'result' variable is 'NoneType' and i got an error that nonetype  have no attribute 'rowcount'.

Comment: before rowcount you need to fetch data

Comment: 'NoneType has no attribute rowcount' still. even i copied your code. BTW the first code was working fine on MySql. i don't know what should i do with postgres

Comment: Dear; i go through the document and everything is like i did. can't figure out the problem

Comment: That document says correctly, "cursor.rowcount returns the total number of database rows that have been modified, inserted, or deleted by the last last execute*()." 
In this case it is a `SELECT` query that is being executed, nothing is modified, inserted or deleted, so you can't use rowcount. You also can't call rowcount from `result` because it is a method of the `cursor` object, and here, `result` is being assigned the return value of cursor.execute() which is `None`; you're trying to call `None`.rowcount and as @nova discovered `nonetype have no attribute 'rowcount'`